# RPi smart mirror

Tags: pi-3

Want one for myself. But I am new... how to build a RPi smart mirror?
[image]

Comment: What is a RPi smart mirror?

Comment: The mirror is completely unrelated to Pi. What you're looking for is "how to put a display behind a mirror", what kind of computer drives the display is completely irrelevant. You can even hook it to a tv running weather channel for similar effect.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/is-it-really-appropriate-to-put-this-question-on-hold

Answer (score 4):

The project "magic mirror" was the cover topic of ["The MagPi", issue 54](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/issues/54/).

> Make your own Magic Mirror in our step-by-step guide in the latest issue of the official Raspberry Pi magazine

You can [download](https://raspberrypi.org/magpi-issues/MagPi54.pdf) it for free.

> Build a Magic Mirror! Our definitive guide to build your very own wonder of IoT and design

Have fun!